# Is it possible program STM32 device wireless?

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I have an STM32-discovery board and I am trying to program it with not using any cables.In the place where I am doing my internship, they first wanted me to program STM32-discovery with UART. I was able to do this by making the necessary connections and using the Flash loader demo. Now my next task is to add an ESP-07 wifi module on the STM32-discovery board, connect this module to the same network as my computer, and wirelessly program it from my computer. No other device is wanted in between (like Raspberry). I did some research on this topic but couldn't come to a conclusion. What I found; I can remote program by connecting the card to a Raspberry or a device called Codegrip. Is it possible to do this with only an ESP-07 without these devices? I will be glad if you just tell me what should I look for.

Comment: You need to write your own software for that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too broad question,

Comment: Is it possible to design all manner of custom bootloaders? Yes it is. Wi-fi is tedious though, since it comes with lots of complexity. Whereas for example Bluetooth can be used as wireless UART in much simpler ways, for point-to-point communication.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to reprogram the STM32 flash wirelessly if the STM32 is running a program that supports this capability.  When you programmed the STM32 via the UART there was a program running on the STM32 that:

1. opened the UART port,
2. received the new program data via the UART (using some protocol),
3. and then programmed that new data onto the flash.

To do likewise wirelessly, the STM32 will need to be running a program that:

1. opens the Wi-Fi port,
2. receives the new program data via Wi-Fi (using some protocol),
3. and then programs that new data onto the flash.

You may have used the STM32 internal ROM bootloader to reprogram via the UART.  And if so then you used the protocol required by that ROM bootloader.  But the ROM bootloader probably does not support Wi-Fi.  So you'll probably be creating your own bootloader program that can communicate over Wi-Fi.  And you might be defining your own protocol for transferring the program data over Wi-Fi.  Or maybe you can apply some established protocol such as FTP.  Search for examples of bootloaders that support OTA (over the air) firmware updates.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions.

1. Write a custom bootloader for the STM32 - the flash is organised with smaller blocks at the start to support that, so you would move your application to higher memory and have the bootloader either jump to the application to load a new application.  The bootloader can then access the Wi-Fi module (and other interfaces) to get updates.
2. Write custom firmware for the ESP0-07 so that it receives and stores the STM32 image, then transfers it to the STM32 using the existing ROM serial bootloader.  In this case you need the details of the bootloader protocol, and it would be useful if the ESP-07 had a GPIO connection to the STM32 reset line so that it can invoke the bootloader without a manual reset.

Either way, you need to write software for one or other of the devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any standard bootloader and connect the Wireless module like ESP32 (Bluetooth and Wifi), ESP8266 (Bluetooth and Wifi), BT-05 (Bluetooth), HM-10 (Bluetooth), etc.

Then create the android application or web application and update the Firmware or application.

If you don't want to use the Standard Bootloader, you can implement your own bootloader and add this OTA feature to that.

We have added the Tutorials step by step. Please refer to [this](https://embetronicx.com/bootloader-tutorials/) if you get time. There we have developed the custom bootloader and updated the Firmware.